# Extracting stderr from pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

My question is simple: Can I `expect()` to see certain output on stderr using pexpect? It seems `pexpect.spawn()` can only be used to expect output on stdout.

Utopian example:

`import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn(...)
child.expect("hi", fd=pexpect.STDERR)`

Or in prose, "expect the string 'hi' on stderr".

I have not found any mention of such a facility in the docs, but I do note that the `child` instance has a `stderr` attribute...

A hack which semi-achieves what I want is to redirect stderr to stdout in the spawn arguments, then we can use regular `expect()`. There must be a better way?

Cheers

Comment: Pexpect runs your subprocess in a pty, so all the standard streams (stdin, stdout and stderr) are pointed to that pty, and the controlling process writes to and reads from that single pty. It doesn't have access to stdout and stderr separately: they will be interleaved in output, like running the process in a regular terminal. If you need separate access, you can start the process with `subprocess.Popen` and then use `pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn` to look at just one of the pipes.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like it will work. Do you have an example and I will mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 6):

For posterity, and based on the comment by [Thomas K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434217/thomas-k), this seems to do what you want:

```
import os
import subprocess
from pexpect import fdpexpect

program = ['/path/to/command', '--arg1', 'value1', '--arg2', 'value2']
devNull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
command = subprocess.Popen(program, stdout=devNull,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
child = fdpexpect.fdspawn(command.stderr)
child.expect('hi')
```

Comment: you should probably use `stdin=DEVNULL` if you don't write to `command.stdin` (pass `'r+b'` to `open()`)