# Make pexpect output stdout to file and stderr to a different file with the help of subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, stdout, stderr, pexpect

I am trying to execute a command with pexpect to wait for a password prompt.

The thing is i would like to save the stdout to a normal logfile and stderr to a seperate error logfile.

I know that pexpect doesnt actually have the capability to seperate stdout and stderr. Everything should supposedly go to stdout.

But i am trying to make it work anyway, but i dont got the skill.

---

This is what i have been able to come up with.

It does save errors in stderr.txt, but nothing appears in stdout.txt

And on top of that the command that is executed with pexpect fails.
It never inserts the password and just iterate trough the list for the next item in the array.

The code i have attempted to make looks like this

---

```
for (h, i) in zip(SourceLines, DestLines):

    SyncoidExecute=SyncoidCommand.replace("SourceDataSet", h)
    SyncoidExecute=SyncoidExecute.replace("DestDataSet", i)

    with open("stdout.txt","wb") as out, open("stderr.txt","wb") as err:
        command = subprocess.Popen(SyncoidExecute, stdout=out, stderr=err, shell=True)
        child = pexpect.spawn(command)
        child.expect('Enter')
        child.sendline(PassWord)
        child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
        child.close()
```

The command to be executed looks like this

```
syncoid UserName@IP:SourceDataSet DestDataSet --compress none --sshcipher chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com --sshport PORT --sshkey /Path/To/Key-File --no-privilege-elevation
```

---

While allso giving me some different errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/darkyere/Scripts/Syncoid/V 0.3 PY/./SynCoid-Iterate.py", line 137, in <module>

    child = pexpect.spawn(command)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 205, in __init__

    self._spawn(command, args, preexec_fn, dimensions)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 266, in _spawn

    self.args = split_command_line(command)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/utils.py", line 88, in split_command_line

    for c in command_line:

TypeError: 'Popen' object is not iterable
```

After googling that i tried with

```
subprocess.run
```

But it allso just gives errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/darkyere/Scripts/Syncoid/V 0.3 PY/./SynCoid-Iterate.py", line 137, in <module>

    child = pexpect.spawn(command)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 205, in __init__

    self._spawn(command, args, preexec_fn, dimensions)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 266, in _spawn

    self.args = split_command_line(command)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/utils.py", line 88, in split_command_line

    for c in command_line:

TypeError: 'CompletedProcess' object is not iterable
```

---

So far it gives stderr.txt but the command never finishes.
And it allways throws python errors at me.

Anyone who have a way to make this work?

Ty for reading and best regards,

Darkyere

Comment: `pexpect.spawn()`'s first param is a string.

Comment: I see that i might have done something wrong there. The idea for this is derived from the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179383/extracting-stderr-from-pexpect where someone uses subprocess and pexpect to only listen to stderr. The only problem is i would like to save both stdout and stderr seperately and still execute the command proberly.